# Which version of Hibernate is JPA 1.0 compliant

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Which version of hibernate is JPA 1.0 compliant.
I know Hibernate 3.6 that we are using supports JPA 2.0

Comment: If it supports JPA 2.0, then it also supports JPA 1.0, surely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hibernate with JPA support is packaged as Hibernate EntityManager, and it's latest version with JPA 1.0 support is **3.4.0.GA** (it includes version 3.2.0.GA of Hibernate Core).

Comment: but in the hibernate distribution for 3.3.2. GA, "hibernate-distribution-3.3.2.GA-dist.zip" there are no jar file for jpa. As is there in the hibernate 3.6 distribution where the file "hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar" is available with in the distribution itself. So where can I find the library file for JPA 1.0 implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but in case someone stumbles on it, I'd like to add the following:

The [Hibernate download page](http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/) states that:
"*...newer ORM releases are backwards compatible with older JPA versions (ex: ORM 4.3 with JPA 1.0)...*"